# How to write a file list with foreign names to a csv file in the terminal?

Tags: ls, csv, unicode

I have some files with names in foreign languages in my terminal folder. On the terminal when I do '`ls`' i see the list on the right in the picture below.

[image]

When I do `ls -t | tail -n +2`, I see the real characters like in the picture below.

[image]

I would like to write the list of filenames in original characters as in the 2nd picture to a csv file? Is there a way to do that? I have found very similar questions here but the filenames were not foreign on those questions. Here how it looks like if i use `ls -t | tail -n +2 > files.csv`

[image]

But I would like to have the list with original names because I need to get meta info from an existing file based on original names where filenames are not in any order and number of files is also different.

On MobaXterm when I go to settings on the terminal the charset is selected as UTF-8(encoding). Also, I have checked if I see UTF-8.

```
~$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

Comment: Does `ls -t | tail -n +2 > file.csv` work?

Comment: thanks Tuyen, yes actually it creates a csv file but characters have different look. I will edit the pic how it look.( I tried this command in quotes before your suggestion but it didn`t do anything.)

Comment: From the picture you attached, the command worked but I guess you opened `csv` file on an app that didn't support that font or didn't recognize that font from your system or your system didn't install the font. Try to install font and restart app.

Comment: Font is one thing, Unicode support is another. It looks like you opened the file in some spreadsheet. Wasn't there an option to choose UTF-8 encoding or something?

Comment: Hi! I have opened the files.csv  in excel on both linux environment and on Windows, it has the same look on both env. I opened the file by right click on the file and didn`t see any UTF-8 encoding etc. Thanks

Comment: Would encoding the file names in the `csv` file as something like base64, help?

Comment: You may also want to set / enable utf8 support in the terminal to see the names in your first image.

Comment: On MobaXterm when I go to settings on the terminal the charset is selected as UTF-8(encoding). If there is an enable utf8 support option i couldn't find  it so far, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like those file names are encoded in UTF-8, your terminal is in UTF-8,  but your locale is not. `locale charmap` probably outputs something like  `ANSI_X3.4-1968` (aka ASCII). ASCII doesn't define any character with a codepoint above 127. Non-ASCII UTF-8 characters are all encoded on 2 or more bytes that are all greater than 127.

`ls` renders those bytes as `?` because they don't form printable characters in ASCII (the current locale charmap).

You'd want to use a locale where the charmap is UTF-8. In your list of *available* locales as reported by `locale -a`, that leaves only `C.UTF-8`.

Run:

```
export LANG=C.UTF-8
locale
```

You may need to unset some `$LC_XXX` variables if they add been set to something else.

Note that Microsoft products may not recognise UTF-8 files as such unless they start with a `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`  character (also used as byte-order-mark in UTF-16, there's no issue with byte ordering in UTF-8).

You can add that character and also convert the line endings to Microsoft format with:

```
unix2dos -m < file.csv > file.ms.csv
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help. I did the export and locale as you described, and this time when i said 'ls' it listed the files with their original names. But the csv file still looks same as on my post.